Snowflake Dynamic query filter
I have a query like below where i look at status of my table execution status. Where i need to search for last 7 days of executions status and for next day based on current date. I want my date filter to be dynamic based on current date. Currently i am using a static filter. But looking to do this dynamically. Any suggestions. I tried with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function but format what i am looking is different because i need to filter very specifically for 7am for dates filter always
SELECT
  SCHEDULED_TIME,
  QUERY_START_TIME,
  COMPLETED_TIME,
  initcap(STATE) as STATE,
  QUERYnumber,
FROM
  table(
      TASK_HISTORY(
      task_name => 'TASK_1',
      scheduled_time_range_start => TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ('2024-07-26T07:00:00.000Z', 'AUTO'),
      scheduled_time_range_end => TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ('2024-08-02T07:00:00.000Z', 'AUTO'),
      result_limit => 10000
    )
  )
ORDER BY
  SCHEDULED_TIME


How about WHERE SCHEDULED_TIME >= DATEADD(day, -7, CURRENT_DATE()) ?

it wont give me in the format i am looking for. Since it needs to always filter at 7aM Zulu time as show in query
